# using a jquery if condition on a span tag to show hide a div element

Tags: jquery, if-statement, onchange

I am trying the following script to detect changes on a span tag and then show or hide a div element. For some reason the if statement is not working. I don't get any errors in my browser and not much information on what can be wrong with it.

```
$('#ch1').on('change',function(){
if('#ch1' > 6) {

        $('#box1').hide(2000);
} else {
        $('#box1').show(2000); 
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to check the elements value, seeing as you're listening for the `change` event.

Also, jQuery has a `toggle` functionality that makes this a little easier

```js
$('#ch1').on('change', function() {
  $('#box1').toggle(this.value < 6);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ch1" value="2" />
<div id="box1" ">Less than six</div>
```

As an FYI, a `span` doesn't change, you'll need an input.

Answer (score 0):

```
At first, create a javascript ready function where you can put the span click code to show/hide div.
```

```js
var temp = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("span").click(function(){     
        if(temp == 1)    
        {
         $('#tempdiv').hide(2000);
            temp = 2;
        }
        else
        {
         $('#tempdiv').show(2000);
            temp = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span>If you click on me, then....</span>
<div id="tempdiv">This is a div that you can show and hide on span.</div>

</body>
</html>
```